# Filter table rows by td value (greater than)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table with some columns and I am trying to hide the rows where the value in a specific `td` is smaller than `1.5`.

It works in the snippet below with no problems but it does not when I am creating an HTML file with exactly the same code from the snippet.

```js
$('#btnFilter').click(function() {
   
    var value = $('#filter').val();

    $('tr').show();

    $('tr td.odds').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() < value)
        {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}


/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #fb887c;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
max-width:50px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#000;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #000;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #000;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #fdfcd3;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#fdb5ad;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#fecbc6;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>STAKE</th>
        <th>Odds</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
        <tr id="Memory4" class="part_detail txtMult">
            <td class="stake">3</td>
            <td class="odds">1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Memory5" class="part_detail txtMult">
            <td class="stake">5</td>
            <td class="odds">1.5</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<br/>

<input type='text' id='filter' />

<button id='btnFilter'>Go</button>
```

Comment: The JS code need to be execute after DOM is loaded. Wrap it in `ready()` or include JS at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: @Tushar The ready function did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it work perfect ,
I put the Javascript into another file and included it before `</body>`
also you can put code in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnFilter').click(function() {

    var value = $('#filter').val();

    $('tr').show();

    $('tr td.odds').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() < value)
        {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried pulling an external file and then I included the script at the bottom of the page (before the body ends) and it did not work. 

If it does, the second step would be to make the input work as a live search. I do not want to use the GO button.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer I used the code on multiple computers and on codepen , jsfiddle , and work good on all of them . I can say the problem in your server if your use code in localhost on windows; propably  it's a  server error and I suggest change your localserver

Comment: If I make it work like this : http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/test.html then I don't have to change things. Do you believe I can make my code work like this? I tried changing the click to onkeyup but with no results.

Comment: As I say before you run into a server bug , this is the page from the url and work like a charm on my localhost : https://i.stack.imgur.com/27CLf.png

Comment: I tried that on my server and then on windows and I faced the same problem. I have not faced this problem again. Do you have any link that could help?

Comment: If you tested it on your server which is mostly Linux-Based and configured well , I can say that the problem might be in you ; I suggest double check your code , check the links again and where & how you link it , also you maybe disable the javascript or you run a `Ad blocker`

Comment: I added the script at the end of the script. I even tried to load it in the header. It works for a second or something and then the page gets refreshed for a reason : http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/stack.html?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer the page doesn't "refreshed" it's "resubmitted"  because you used a `form` tag as container of inputs and button , if you remove or replace the `form` tag with `div` or whatever the page will work fine

Comment: I used another way now. I found a ready solution and it works without a button which was my second step. I will test both codes in the future to see which one is faster. Thanks @Kain

Comment: @ApoloRadomer you are welcome , please mark the question as answered .